React Native RCTFabric - No type or protocol named 'RCTDebuggingOverlayViewProtocol'
After upgrading to the latest version of react-native I've suddenly run into the issue with RCTFabric.
    "react-native": "0.74.0",

1. No type or protocol named 'RCTDebuggingOverlayViewProtocol'
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'DebuggingOverlayShadowNode'
3. Use of undeclared identifier 'DebuggingOverlayShadowNode'
4. Use of undeclared identifier 'RCTDebuggingOverlayHandleCommand'

Did anyone face something like this?


I had the exact same issue after updating to react-native version 0.74.0.
For me the problem got solved when I removed the dependency react-native-macos, as I anyway don't need it. It seems that there is some dependency issue with the new version.
Hopefully that can solve your problem as well.

This was exactly it – react-native-macos was a peerDependency of some another library, so just wanted to get rid of the warning, even though I didn't need it. With update to 0.74.0, it started causing issue – which was impossible to track back to react-native-macos. Thank you!

Thank you for the post, I had the same issue, after removing react-native-macos it was resolved.

Perfect, I would like to also remove dependency 'Apple' from my project 'World', but there are some apes using that platform :/

see this link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34625#issuecomment-1917685509
I had the same issue when upgrading to RN 0.73.3.
Clean your project, delete yarn.lock and ios build folder. Run yarn and pod install. This should fix it. This has nothing to do with git, so do not attempt to do weird stuff with git, you will lose your files.
